# Installing 12.04 through Update Manager on a XP/ubuntu dual-boot

Tags: 12.04, wireless, upgrade

I currently have a dual-boot system running XP Pro SP3 with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I decided to upgrade to 12.04 using the Update Manager from the network and NOT using ISO CD version.

Now that I am in the middle of 12.04 installation, I have this immense fear that this upgrade from update manager on the network server may affect my Win XP OS and may render it un-bootable.

I tried backing up files while its upgrading to Ubuntu but it does not recognize any external media like external HDD.

What should I do?

Comment: Don't afraid this will not mess up your windows. anyway there is many solutions to restore your windows in case something wrong happens(hope no). Finish first and let us know the results

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I have 13 mints left for the 'Installing the upgrades" followed by "Cleaning up" and "Restarting the computer". I will definitely provide an update once the system reboots after the installation is complete. Thank you again for your prompt response. This is a great forum...

Comment: You are welcome. Any more questions i'm here to help as much as i can

Answer (score 0):

You can do several things to be more safe (before and after):

1. if you're using nt bootloader (windows default bootloader), you can backup your mbr using "dd if=/dev/sdX of=~/sdX-mbr.bin bytes=512 count=1" when X is your physical drive letter (not windows drive letter). when you want to restore mbr you just change the arguments between if and of.
2. from windows installation you have something like "Recovery mode" and from there you can run fixmbr which will rewrite nt bootloader into mbr.

in any case, you can always let GRUB be your bootloader, it recognizes windows partitions and can chain bootloading (switch from GRUB to nt bootloader).

READ MORE ABOUT BACKUP MBR AND FIXMBR BECAUSE THEY CAN BE DANGEROUS.

you can always try to do those things in a virtual machine before doing it on the physical.